# Database based Priority Queue

Tags: database, priority-queue

does anyone know of a good database based Priority Queue implementation?

I'm dealing with large amounts of data so keeping it all in memory is unfeasible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want a [Message Queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue)?

There are several good ones, both proprietary and open source.  For a simple API, check [memcacheq](http://memcachedb.org/memcacheq/), for a more complete, high-performace, take a look at [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Comment: No, I need a queue, sorted by priority, but instead of storing everything in memory I want to store it on a database.